# 2D Water effect in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working with libGDX and I'd like to reproduce the water behavior we can find in games like Terraria or Go To Hell. The water must be able to flow under the effect of gravity and adapt it's shape to the container's shape.

Actually I don't really know were to start, therefore I have no code to show. I found some tutorial for water effects like reflexion or physics with Box2D, but nothing that I want for my project. If you have some clue it'd be great.

Thanks !

Comment: It depends on how you want your water physics. For Go to Hell style physics, look at @sm4's answer. If you want block-like water physics you'll have to take a different approach, but it should be easier (although a bit more blocky). You could also check out [this document](http://fumufumu.q-games.com/gdc2010/shooterGDC.pdf) on how [PixelJunk Shooter](https://www.google.dk/search?q=pixeljunk+shooter+water&rlz=1CAACAH_enDK642DK642&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=945&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI-ZKs742oxwIVht0sCh2uYQSH) did it.

Answer (score 5):

The water effect can be achieved by using [LiquidFun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) physics engine based on Box2D. There is an [LiquidFun extension](https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension) for LibGDX available.